# Why do we need this special === operator?

Tags: php, language-features

I've used C++ and Java before and they don't have this `===` operator.

How come they manage without it but in languages like PHP its key.

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 10):

Actually `equals` in Java and `==` in C# act like `===` does in php. I.e. `"24".equals(24)` will return false.

What java and C# don't have an equivalent of is PHP's `==` (i.e. an operator/method such that `"24".fuzzyEquals( 24 )` would return true). And that's because C# and Java are strongly typed and such an operator would be against their philosophy.

Answer (score 3):

Because PHP is not type safe. == compares 2 values, but === compares the values AND checks if their class types are the same.

I believe "2" == 2 returns true, while "2" === 2 returns false.

Answer (score 2):

when we say "A is equal to B" this can mean several quite different things

- A and B are the same thing
- A and B have the same value, that is, their values are not distinguishable for a third party
- A and B can be converted to strings (or numbers) that are equal
- A and B have the same hash value

etc

most languages do have different operators or functions for different kinds of equality , see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_%28relational_operator%29#Object_identity_vs._Content_equality

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, this is the same in JavaScript and according to JSLint should ALWAYS be used as a type-check, which technically makes == redundant. But I guess that's just personal preference